# A Seemingly Simple List Indexing Out of Range Error

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm working in Jupyter notebook and practicing web scraping. I wrote:

```
rows = [] 
rows.append(['Rank', 'Company Name', 'Webpage', 'Description',
        'Location', 'Year end', 'Annual sales rise over 3 years',
        'Sales f000s', 'Staff', 'Comments'])
rows[1]
```

I just want to access the 2nd element. Why is this an error "list index out of range"? I couldn't find a question similar to mine.

Comment: a list include another list,`rows = [[...]]`

Comment: Answering how to access the second element in your case: Use `rows[0][1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.append` adds *one* item to the list. `list.extend` *concatenates* the base list with the target. Consider this:

```
>>> x = [1, 2]
>>> y = [1, 2]

>>> x.append([3,4])
>>> x
[1, 2, [3, 4]]

>>> y.extend([3, 4])
>>> y
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

What you are looking for is `list.extend` as `append`ing a list into an empty creates a single-element list whose only element is another list. Extending the list adds each item to the empty list, thus making the list a multi-element list.

Answer (score 0):

because need `extend`:

```
rows = [] 
rows.extend(['Rank', 'Company Name', 'Webpage', 'Description',
        'Location', 'Year end', 'Annual sales rise over 3 years',
        'Sales f000s', 'Staff', 'Comments'])
rows[1]
```

It does not works because you're not merging you're appending the list into another list

SO it will be:

```
[['Rank', 'Company Name', 'Webpage', 'Description',
        'Location', 'Year end', 'Annual sales rise over 3 years',
        'Sales f000s', 'Staff', 'Comments']]
```

that which contains one element

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out. How come this does not work for append method?

Comment: @NimbleTortoise because `append` only takes one argument so, it's a list so adds the list into the other list so will be nested, please accept if it works